# Receiving a C++ object in a slot

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to send a C++ object to QML via signal-slot :

```
class TaskInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ taskName)
    ...

// constructors
public:
    TaskInfo();
    TaskInfo(QIODevice *in);
    TaskInfo(TaskInfo &&taskInfo);
    TaskInfo(const TaskInfo &taskInfo); // it's just copy all variable
    ...
}
```

and I have a class to send TaskInfo object to QML:

```
class DLDataConverter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void taskAdded_testQML(const TaskInfo taskInfo);
    void taskAdded_useQString(const QString taskInfo);
    ...
}
```

I also emit a signal and receive it in QML:

```
void DLDataConverter::addItem(const TaskInfo &taskInfo)
{
    emit taskAdded_testQML(taskInfo);
    emit taskAdded_useQString(taskInfo.getInfoToString());
}
```

QML code:

```
Connections {
    target: DLDataConverter

    onTaskAdded_testQML: {
        console.log(taskInfo);
    }

    onTaskAdded_useQString: {
        console.log(taskInfo);
    }
}
```

onTaskAdded_useQString signal is working perfectly, but onTaskAdded_testQML prints 'undefined'.

I have registered these types :

`qmlRegisterType<TaskInfo>("taskInfo", 1, 0, "TaskInfo");`
`qmlRegisterSingletonType<DLDataConverter>("Singleton.DLDataConverter", 1, 0, "DLDataConverter", dataObj);`

I can create `TaskInfo` object and it works well:

```
TaskInfo{
    id: t
}


Connections {
    target: DLDataConverter

    onTaskAdded_testQML: {
        console.log(t.name);  // print default value, is "Noname"
        console.log(taskInfo);  // print 'undefined'
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `TaskInfo` derive from `QObject`?

Comment: @cmannett85 it does, given the first code snippet. I'm wondering if that `taskInfo` reference used in `addItem` is correctly handled in the code. Following the usual bad habit of most OPs, we just see a small bit of code. :-|

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Woops, should have read the first code block properly...  My hunch is that it's because the OP has declared the signal arg `QObject` instead of  `QObject*`, I'm surprised that even compiles due to the lack of copy constructor.

Comment: @cmannett85  Good sight man! Most probably that's the problem. :)

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo  i can create `TaskInfo` object in QML and it's work well, just can't send `TaskInfo` object via signal-slot.

Comment: Try to revisit your code as @cmannett85 suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QML uses data from Qt by converting every parameter to `QVariant` and then, if possible, to native JavaScript values. If they cannot be converted to JS, you can still copy and pass them with JS but you won't be able to use them. Without extending `QVariant`, only `QObject*` can be hold in `QVariant` and are thread by JS that its properties, slot and signals are visible to JS. Any pointer to object, whose class is derived from `QObject`, is implicitly converted to `QObject*` by `QVariant`. So you can freely define the signal of a pointer to your class as:

```
class DLDataConverter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void taskAdded_testQML(TaskInfo *taskInfo);
    void taskAdded_useQString(const QString taskInfo);
    ...
}
```

Pointers introduces the problem of object lifetime, so you should definitely learn more about how to [manage the ownership of objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership).
If you create your object in Qml like this:

```
TaskInfo{
    id: t
}
```

you create an object that has a `parent` whose lifetime determine the lifetime of the object itself. The pointer is bound to the name `t` inside a local QML context.

Comment: + For the link to C++/QML data ownership

Comment: Thanks this works! Is there any way to send non-pointer argument in signal so that it works in QML side ?

Comment: @knocker_d Any [QVariant that is convertible](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) to [basic types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-basictypes.html) should work in QML. Any other [QVariant that is register to metatype](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html) can by passed by QML, but to be usefull in QML, it need to be a structure declared as Q_GADGET (in Qt >= 5.5).

Comment: @Arpegius: Yes, thanks. I'm porting code from Qt c++ to QML. If I use non-pointer in signal argument which is custom class and registered to metatype then in slot I see QVariant<MyClass>. Can I somehow "cast" it to MyClass instance inside QML ?

Comment: @knocker_d that depends on what MyClass is, if it inherit QObject you doing it terrible wrong and should stop that, pointer is the only way.  If not, you can add Q_GADGET makro to MyClass and then use Q_PROPERTY and Q_INVOKABLE to be usable in QML (No SIGNALS and SLOTS supoted).

Comment: @Arpegius: thank you, very helpful. MyClass inherits QObject but I believe you I don't use it. In the program I emit signal from c++ worker thread into QML. Before emit I create new MyClass object in heap. After emitting I use myclass.deleteLater() - there can be 100 emits per second so I have to delete objects at some point. Is it ok ?

Comment: @knocker_d if you put pointer to MyClass when emiting signal it is no big deal, but the deleteLater should not be called in worked, because after you recive it in QML there so no way it could remain valid. QML reference to QObcjet* will become null after destructor of this obcject is called.

Comment: @knocker_d but if you put value copy of your MyClass to signal, god only knows how much realocation of this object will happends, and of course it will be unusuable in QML.